# what's the period for state in Markov chain?

Tags: probability, markov-process, graphical-model

[image]

I have two questions:

1.What's the period for state A or does A have a period? Is there a specified name for those states like state A who gives all to other state and won't be returned back?

2. Are B and C called recurrent state or communicate state?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to know the *classes of comunication*. A *class of communication* is all the states where you can go and come back . Here there is {**A**} the first class and {**B**,**C**} the second one. In a class, all the states have the same ***period***.

In some article, by definition **A** has a *period*=0. It's a *transient state*.

B and C have a period of one ( *there is loop on themselves*). And yes they are recurrent states, even more, they are positive recurrent.

You can check here, it's a good explanation :

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152991/how-can-i-spot-positive-recurrence

But for those questions you should go to : https://math.stackexchange.com/